# php memory error in depenency injection

Tags: php, url-routing, factory, memory-limit

I would have used google but I'm going out and hope u guys can help me with a solution or tell me what I'm doing wrong by the time I get back.

I passed in an instance of my factory to my controller and based on something I want to use the factory to begin another instance of a controller that is related to this one bit I get

```
 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\object_factory_inc.php on line 19
```

I'm here is the factory and the controller I'm trying to call it from

**factory**

```
/* The purpose of this class is to create the instance of a class when needed and how needed.
        For example we could have created the controller object inline but in recognition
        of the polymorphic behavior of controllers we have the decided to create it in our object-
        factory class(this class) which serves to hide the logic of creating the correct instance of
        a specified controller. 

        For example the 'build_index_controller' function uses the second parameter
        of the parameters passed to it to decide on the instance of the index to call
        */


class object_factory_inc
{
    public function build_controller($controller_name,array $controller_params)
    {
        $indexed_controller_params=array_values($controller_params);
        $controller_name=strtolower($controller_name);


        if(!isset($indexed_controller_params[0]))
        {

            $controller_name=$controller_name."_controller";
            return new $controller_name($this,$controller_params);

        }

        else
        {
            $controller_build_function="build_".$controller_name."_controller";
            method_exists($this,$controller_build_function)?$this->$controller_build_function($controller_name,$controller_params,$indexed_controller_params):$this->controller_doesn't_exist($controller_build_function);
                }

            }

            private function build_index_controller($controller_name,array $controller_params,array $indexed_controller_params)
            {
                strtolower($indexed_controller_params[0]);
                switch ($indexed_controller_params[0])
                {
                    case "s":
                    $controller_name=$controller_name."_search_controller";
                    return new $controller_name($this,$controller_params);
                    break;

                    case "admin":
                    $controller_name=$controller_name."_admin_controller";
                    return new $controller_name($this,$controller_params);
                    break;

                    case "loggedin":
                    $controller_name=$controller_name."_loggedin_controller";
                    return new $controller_name($this,$controller_params);
                    break;

                    default://if it doesn't exist just run default controller behaviour consider running 404
            $controller_name=$controller_name."_controller";
            return $controller_name($this,$controller_params);
        }

    }


    private function controller_doesnt_exist($controller_name)
    {
        echo "404 error ".$controller_name." doesn't exist on this server";
    }
}
```

The controller I'm trying to run it from:

```
     class index_controller
    {

    protected $parameters=array();
    protected $default_operation='view';
    protected $object_factory;

    public function __construct(object_factory_inc $factory,array $parameters )
     {
        $this->object_factory=$factory;
        $this->parameters=$parameters;
        $this->varify_controller();
        //print_r($parameters);
        //var_dump($factory);
        //require_once "views/index_view.php";


      }

      private function varify_controller()
      {
          if(true)//if logged in session is set;
          {
              $indexd_parameteres=array_values($this->parameters);
              $indexd_parameteres[0]='loggedin';
              $this->object_factory->build_controller("index",$this->parameters);
          }
      }

    }

the normal way the controllers are usually called are from the index here it is

    require_once 'includes/config.php';


        $route=isset($_GET['action'])?new router_controller($_GET['action']):new router_controller($_GET['action']="/index");
        $route->parse_route();
        $object_factory=new object_factory_inc;
        $controller=$object_factory->build_controller($route->get_controller(),$route->get_request_data());
```

sorry about the long question just wanted I gave you all you needed thanks in advance also if I'm doing something totally wrong please if you're gonna direct me to google at least give me something to google.

Comment: its this line "  $indexed_controller_params=array_values($controller_params);" in the object factory its kinda strange as the error the line was on changed the moment i commented out the lines in the index controller. im not sure but i think its reffreing to the line 19 as that  was autoloaded in the index controller. the problem arised when i tried to build a diffrent instance of the controller in the controller. i also tested the object factory before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is recreating the `IndexController` very time.

```
$this->object_factory->build_controller("index",$this->parameters);
```

When you create your `index_controller` via your object factory (line above) the new `Index_Controller` makes a call to `varify_controller` as this is defined within the `__construct()` (executed automatically when the `Index_Controller` is first instantiated).

`varify_controller()` contains yet another call to `build_controller("index",$this->parameters);` so we are then back to the beginning, endlessly creating new index controllers until you exceed the memory limit.

You can avoid these issues in the future by using the constructor for *constructing* the object. This should only include performing tasks that are need to get the object ready to be used, i.e. setting object properties or resolving object arguments.

Comment: +1 for finding the loop. Also, I would add that this is why constructors should not be "doing work" in you code. Makes for mistakes that are hard to track down.

Comment: oh i c the error i sent the nchanged varible in the varify function while trying to build the other instance of the index controller. @toreko it needs to be done in order to build the controller. if its not that means it shouldnt be built

Comment: will test your solution when i get bk

Comment: @alex_zander I hope you went to buy a keyboard. Your current one seems to be failing.

Comment: @terešk lol indeed i also thaught about what u said while gone and will be taking that out of the constructer i just wanted to keep the code minimal. will update and tell if its fixed

Comment: @alex_zander the thing about factories is that they can not only initiate different classes of object, but also *prepare* those instances for consumption in the rest of application. And another note: you really should look into namespaces and how they can be used both for autoloading and for improvement of factories.

Comment: @tereško thanks will definatly be the next thing i research and employ in my never ending battle to improve +1

Comment: @alex_zander , FYI, the votes on comments have no affect on reputation points. For comments the votecount determines if they are visible in "top 5 comments" for that particular answer. It becomes important, when comment explains why said answer is bad/wrong/harmful. Or, if you downvote an answer, it is a common curtest to leave a comment, which describes the reason. In that case votes on comment let you indicate that you agree with state reason for down-voting.

Comment: @tereško Oh i c thanks for the info i will definatly keep that and getting a new keyboard in mind :-)

Answer (score 0):

increase memory by addding the line  at the top of your page

`ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

Comment: Because it is the stupidest possible way to fix an endless loop.

Comment: @user2092317 thanks for trying to help i appreciate it dont worry about toresko he is horrid to everybody